# Excel VBA macro cell copy under each other

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a macro which makes the followings:

1. open all files on a Directory (more than 600 files)
2. modify the I36 and I37 values
3. Copy I48 into file 'AKL LASER SUM W27_36 macro1.xls' A3 cell
4. Copy L36 into file 'AKL LASER SUM W27_36 macro1.xls' B3 cell
5. ALL FILES I48 and L36 copy continously under each other to 'AKL LASER SUM W27_36 macro1.xls' file from A3 and B3 (so next file open, modify I36 and I37, after copy I48 and L36 to A4 and B4)

With this I can open and modify all files well, and copy the cells but only every time to A3 and B3, not under each other.

Thanks

```
Sub OpenAllWorkbooks()

    Dim MyFiles As String

    MyFiles = Dir("D:\GTMS\AKL Laser 4 W27_36\*.xls")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""

    Workbooks.Open "D:\GTMS\AKL Laser 4 W27_36\" & MyFiles


    Range("I36").Value = 2.03
    Range("I37").Value = 2.19

    Range("I48").Copy _
    Workbooks("AKL LASER SUM W27_36 macro1.xls").Worksheets("Munka1").Range("A3")

    Range("L36").Copy _
    Workbooks("AKL LASER SUM W27_36 macro1.xls").Worksheets("Munka1").Range("B3")

    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    MyFiles = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a variable to keep track of which row you are currently writing to, it becomes quite easy:

```
Sub OpenAllWorkbooks()

    Dim MyFiles As String
    Dim destRow As Long
    destRow = 3

    MyFiles = Dir("D:\GTMS\AKL Laser 4 W27_36\*.xls")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""

        Workbooks.Open "D:\GTMS\AKL Laser 4 W27_36\" & MyFiles

        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
            .Range("I36").Value = 2.03
            .Range("I37").Value = 2.19

            Workbooks("AKL LASER SUM W27_36 macro1.xls").Worksheets("Munka1").Cells(destRow, "A").Value = .Range("I48").Value

            Workbooks("AKL LASER SUM W27_36 macro1.xls").Worksheets("Munka1").Cells(destRow, "B").Value = .Range("L36").Value

            destRow = destRow + 1

        End With

        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name

        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

        MyFiles = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

I also changed the code slightly so that it doesn't use a `Copy` command - that sometimes causes issues if the user is doing anything else which uses the clipboard while the macro is running.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: I am now a very beginner in VBA, but I like it :)